# Decay of Fourier transform of pushforward measure

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, pushforward

Let $A\subset [0,1]$ be closed and let $\tilde{A}:=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|\in A\}$. Assume $\nu$ is a finite measure supported on $\tilde{A}$ s.t. its Fourier transform decays as $\frac{n-1+\alpha}{2}$. In symbols

$$ \hat{\nu}(\xi) = \int e^{-i\langle \xi, x \rangle}d\nu(x)  $$
$$ | \hat{\nu}(\xi)| \le \|\xi\|^{-\frac{n-1+\alpha}{2}}$$

Let $\mu$ be the pushforward measure of $\nu$ on $[0,1]$ via $\|\cdot\|$, i.e.
$$ \mu([a,b])= \nu(\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\| \in [a,b] \} )$$ 
What can I conclude on the decay of $\mu$? I would expect that $ | \hat{\mu}(t)| \le |t|^{-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ but I'm having a hard time in trying to prove it. If $\nu$ were radial I should be able to get to the conclusion using Bessel functions, but in the general case I don't know how to proceed. I thought I could consider the averages of $\hat{\nu}$ over the spheres, i.e. 
$$ f(\xi) = \int_{S^{n-1}} \hat{\nu}(\|\xi\| \theta) \, d\sigma^{n-1}(\theta) $$
but then I don't know how to conclude that $f$ is the Fourier transform of  some measure supported in $\tilde{A}$.

Comment: The decay of $\mu$ is related to the regularity of $\hat{\nu}$, not to the decay of $\hat{\nu}$. For example, is $\hat{\nu}$ has integrable continuous partial derivatives of any order, then Fourier inversion applies and show that $\nu$ has a density which decays at infinity more quickly that power functions.

Comment: Did you mean that $\nu$ is supported on $A$?

Comment: @YuvalPeres no I want $\nu$ to be supported on the $n$-dimensional radial set, and then define $\mu$ as the pushforward of $\nu$, so that $\mu$ is a measure on the unit interval.

Comment: *If $\nu$ were radial I should be able to get to the conclusion using Bessel functions* Erm, the radial symmetrization of $\nu$ has the same push-forward and not worse decay of the Fourier transform, so what is the issue then?

Comment: @fedja Yes you are right. This is an old question of mine, back then I thought that the radial symmetry of $\nu$ would suffice, but in fact this is not the case (at least I don't see it). In some later attempt, I (think I) managed to prove that $\mu$ decays as expected if we work in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $n$ of the form $1+4k$. The argument is indeed a Bessel function argument. I never obtained the general result though.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355999/fourier-dimension-of-radial-set